# as small as a world and as large as alone

Tags: phrases, comparison, poetry

From a poem *maggie and milly and molly and may*
written by E.E. Cummings

> May came home with a smooth round stone
>   **as small as a world** and **as large as alone**.

What do **as small as a world** and **as large as alone** mean? Are they phrases?

Why is a world small and alone large?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's LitCrit. But I think it's fair to say that cummings is trying to make you ask those questions **of yourself**.

Comment: while the question certainly inspires some off-topic-ish answers, it's of vital importance to language learners! if OP is reading e.e. cummings to help learn English, certainly he needs help figuring out which phrases are English and which are... e.e. cummings being e.e. cummings.

Comment: What is 'LitCrit", literature critics?

Comment: Literary Criticism. The racket I used to be in.

Comment: @StoneyB That explains a lot. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

e.e. cummings plays with the language quite a bit. His writing is beautiful but would be a frustrating source to try to learn English from!

"As small as a world" makes sense grammatically (it means: the same size as a world, which is small). It doesn't make sense semantically (since, as you say, "why is a world small?")

"as large as alone" is not grammatically correct, prescriptively or descriptively. however, the word "alone" sounds like "a lone" (where "lone" as far as I know is not a word) so that phonetically "as small as a world and as large as alone" at first sounds like a completely normal sentence before you stop and think about the semantics of it. I imagine this was the effect he was going for.

Comment: Of course "lone" is a word! Have you never heard of "The Lone Ranger"?!

Comment: :-) you're right. should have said "not a noun."

Comment: +1, but I'd say that descriptively it's "non-standard" rather than "grammatically incorrect".

Comment: I agree with @snail. _Despite_ its unusual construct, I had no problem deciphering "as large as alone." _Because_ of its unusual construct, I found the words beautifully inspirational. Imagine if an editor had forced mr. cummings change the words to "as large as the feeling of being lonely and isolated." _Blech, ick_.

Comment: interesting. I both disagree and agree. My definition of "descriptively correct" is "something a native English speaker would spontaneously utter" and I maintain that native English speakers don't put "alone" here naturally. If you mean "something a native English speaker can spontaneously understand" then we agree. I definitely agree that it's beautiful and that it should not be edited! Perhaps what is needed is a four way contrast between "prescriptively correct/descriptively correct/exotic but poetically interesting play with words / gibberish."

Comment: Put differently, I don't believe in prescriptive rules. If a foreign language learner wants to sound like a native speaker, for instance, they ought to say "me and John went to the store," even though the so-called "proper" English is "John and I." But I do believe in descriptive rules. If someone with a noticeable foreign accent said "as large as alone," I would assume they were confused about the language. (I also acknowledge that, unfortunately, language learners must learn the prescriptive "rules" in order to be taken seriously when they write.)

Comment: @hunter English is an analytic language with very little inflectional morphology, so words hop between categories with ease; as a result, zero derivation is highly productive, though we usually reject it in standard English.  Nonetheless, you must admit zero derivation in a general description of non-standard English, and if you do, then it's grammatically correct; *alone* is a noun derived from *alone*, so it parses.  But of course, it's non-standard.

Comment: i agree that zero derivation happens in non-standard English; i disagree that native english speakers would zero-derive alone from an adverb into a noun in this context in spontaneously produced utterances.

Comment: @hunter Spontaneous is not a requirement.

Comment: @snailboat it is clear that we disagree about what "descriptively correct English" means. For the perspective of a language learner, I don't think our debate is relevant; clearly he should not say "as large as alone" if he hopes to be understood, in formal or informal speech. We can continue this on meta if you feel strongly that he should in fact try to zero-derive this.

Comment: We could continue it on meta even though I believe no such thing, but I fail to see the point.  After all, you said yourself you don't believe in prescriptivism.  And that is what prescriptivism is--usage advice--and there's no reason in principle why it needs to disagree with descriptive grammar on the points where the two overlap.  And indeed, many descriptive linguists have opinions about language and will even give advice if asked! ;-)

Comment: The O.P.'s questions were: "What does _as large as alone_ mean?" (you've answered that admirably) and "Is it a phrase?" (Answer: not really; it's just poetic line from a poem). As for the non-native learning Engish, these are fair questions; I'm sorry to see four close votes already. As for the grammaticality of the eloquent words, I can't see where the O.P. asked for much elaboration on that. Had it been a more standard construct, I doubt there would have been a question to begin with.

Comment: you are right -- I am reading too much into OP's questions! Sorry.

Comment: I believe in strict, prescriptive grammar rules, and I've gotten into quite a few arguments -- I mean "conversations" -- here and on ELU about the topic. But that said, I don't for a moment suggest that "not a complete, grammatically correct sentence" at all means "should not be spoken or written by a human being". In poetry, especially, writers routinely violate normal rules of grammar for poetic effect. And I would think obviously, statements that are highly appropriate and effective in a love song would not be appropriate in a discussion about automotive engineering, etc.

Comment: Oh, and: ESPECIALLY when talking to people trying to learn the language, I think it makes very good sense to point out when a statement is acceptable for formal writing versus casual conversation, for poetry versus technical discussions, etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

Someone trying to learn English should be very cautious about what he makes of poetry and song lyrics. These often do not follow regular grammar rules and in general may use the language in unusual ways.

"As small as a world" is surely meant to be a surprising statement. We normally think of the world as very large. Note that he does not outright assert that the world is small -- he does not say, "Contrary to popular belief, the world is really rather small." Instead, he makes the statement indirectly in a comparison, as if the smallness of the world was something that everyone took for granted.

"As large as alone" is not grammatically correct because "alone" is an adverb and sometimes-adjective, while the phrase calls for a noun. But again, the writer is trying to indirectly say that the state of being alone is something very large ... whatever he means by that.

Comment: I found the phrase _as large as alone_ to be wonderously beautiful. Such a shame to call it "not grammatically correct," no matter what the dictionary and grammar books may say.

Comment: @J.R. I dislike grammar books as much as anyone -- they teach people ridiculous "rules" like "don't end a sentence with a preposition" or that "me and lee" cannot be the subject of a sentence. These "rules" don't accurately describe english. However, that's not what Jay's answer is doing. e.e. cummings is playing with the language here. You do a disservice to a language learner by pretending he will be easily understood if he copies this use of the language. If you really feel that I'm wrong, you should post as a separate answer to the question that the speaker should use this phrase.

Comment: Personally I love grammar books. But regardless, a phrase like "as large as alone" may be beautiful in the context of a poem, but I certainly would not encourage anyone to use it in general conversation. "I can't carry this by myself. It's as large as alone." No, no one will have any idea what you're trying to say.